# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googlemaps'

Tags: python, django, google-maps

I am a newcomer to Django python programming. Now I am working on the server side. I want to use google maps API, my view.py is like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from googlemaps import *
# Create your views
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='A')

def index(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA')
        return geocode_result
```

Also, I have already installed 'googlemaps' using pip. And when I import it in IDE, nothing goes wrong. But when I want to start the server to test the code, the server won't run and tells me ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googlemaps', I am confused that I have already downloaded it and added it in settings.py, importing in IDE also seems fine. But where I did wrong makes it fail to start the server?

Comment: Are you using virtualenv or something like that? It seems you are not serving on the same environment you installed the library

Comment: I am not using that, is the environment of anaconda and python itself like virtualenv?

Answer (score 1):

Change `from googlemaps import *` to `import googlemaps`

What `from googlemaps import *` does is that it imports all the contents of the `googlemaps` module. `import googlemaps` imports the whole `googlemaps` module as a whole.

Comment: That don't work so I changed to import *, also won't work

Comment: @ParthSharma What does `googlecode` have to do with the `googlemaps` module?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working two different ways (assuming valid API key). Either:

```
from googlemaps import Client
gmaps = Client(key='A')
```

or:

```
from googlemaps import *
gmaps = Client(key='A')
```

Do either of these work for you?

If you're still having problems, there's a good chance it's related to your virtualenv (if using). Try running:

```
pip freeze
```

from command line and searching for the requisite library.

If you don't have an API key, you may of course want to consider using geopy. Last I checked, didn't require API key.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I have just tried, now, I can't even import googlemaps. I am using Visual studio, and it tells me that it can't analyze 'googlemaps', the IntelliSense may be lost. But sometimes, it can be imported correctly, but finally, when I want to start server, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to install the module manually in my notebook, so I did this:

```
!pip install googlemaps requests==2.31.0
import googlemaps
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='MY_API_KEY')
```

Answer (score 0):

`pip install googlemaps` worked for me.

After installing, I had to reload my script window, I use VSCode